# Can I publish my domain's ssl certificate's private key?

Tags: tls, key

I want to buy a new domain (example.com) and a Wildcard certificate for that domain (*.example.com) from namecheap. Then I will set up an NS server to define a rule to resolve part of my subdomain to every ipv4 address, then I will write a tool that everyone can start a https website with a ipv4 address with my domain, I will put that tool into github or someplace, so everyone can use it to start a website very easily.

But the private key of that domain's ssl certificate will include in that tool. I know this is will drop the security of https to http, but I do not care, and will tell the users of the tool of the insecurity. I just want to use https to get past some firewalls easier.

Can I do it? How will others effect?

Comment: We cannot comment on legalities here. What namecheap might do sounds like a great question to ask of their support.

Comment: "... tell the users of the tool ..." including all the visitors of all the subdomains that you want the public to set up and control? How will you notify *me* if I visit a site that gets set up like this?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to create something that CloudFlare already does (for free). And as for creating a website with TLS, there is LetsEncrypt that offers TLS certificates for free, too. Even GitHub allows you set up TLS websites for free, and if someone wants to set up a download repo, AWS S3 does this for free (under certain conditions). You might need to explain why you want to offer what others do for free but in a way that significantly reduces security for visitors.

Comment: Other are affected in the sense that their visitors can easily be intercepted now, without any indication that it is happening. Why would **anyone** use your service, if they can get a product that costs just as much nothing **and** is secure?

Comment: @MechMK1 When I have a server and an ip address and do not have register a domain.I think it should be useful.

Comment: @schroeder thanks for your help, I have already change the question. I think this question is so stupid to ask.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is common that a certificate gets revoked if the private key is known to be compromised. Publishing the private key so that it is known publicly is obviously compromise of the secrecy of the private key.

Comment: I just want the private key to be known publicly. Why can I not use a tool(tls) as what I want?

Comment: @bronzeman: *"Why can I not use a tool(tls) as what I want?"* - You can use the tools like you want as long as it does not affect anybody else.  But if you publish the private key everybody could take it and do an undetectable man in the middle attack on such connections. And since you want to make other use of your service this problem will affect others.

Comment: @bronzeman Why even offer HTTPS in the first place then?

Comment: @bronzeman "Why can I not use a tool(tls) as what I want?" -- this is a fundamentally different question (and motivation) from what you asked. I suspect that you have an X/Y problem here and you might get what you want if you explained the actual problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

The viewers of the website can be man in the middle attack when they view the website.

The browser tells the viewers of the website that the website is secure, but it is not secure because of this man in the middle attack.

So this action will affect following:

- The viewers of the website , their passwords may be stolen, but they do not know it, because the browser do not tell them that the website is not secure.
- The reputation of the Certificate Authority will became worse if it do not revoke the certification because it do not tell that the website is not secure when the users' passwords was stolen, when the Certificate Authority know that the private key of this website is publish in some place.

Comment: How does this scenario affect the reputation of the browser?

Comment: @MechMK1 I think the browsers should warning user when the browsers find that the private key of the current website is compromised.

Comment: This is not the job of the browser, it's the job of the Certificate Authority. And the Certificate Authority, once they found out, will revoke the certificate.

Comment: Good to know that,I will change the answer.  So the browser trusts the Certificate Authority, and the Certificate Authority trusts the website owner.

Comment: The CA doesn't trust the owner out of nowhere. The CA verifies that they actually own that domain. Else I could go and claim that I own google.com. Think of it more like "The browser trusts that the CA verified the domain with due diligence, and thus we can trust the domain."

Comment: @MechMK1 Good point. I think the CA trust the website owner to not to publish his private key, and report the private key lost to the ca. I do not think this thing can be verified by dns or something.

Comment: It's not necessarily the owner who has to report it. It just needs to get to the CA's attention. And no, it has nothing to do with DNS. Today, OCSP is used.

Comment: @MechMK1 yes, OCSP is used, I have used it with let's encrypt with DNS and tls.